# Shrink font size and right-align fonts for reveal.js presentations

Tags: markdown, pandoc, reveal.js

HI there: I am writing some lectures in markdown and converting them to reveal.js slides. Honestly, it's working great, except there are some basic features I'd like to modify but I just don't know my way around CSS.

How can I:

1. left-align most of the text on the slides.
2. shrink the font size of the body text on most of the slides. I'd like to do this in general, but I specifically have to do this for the page of references.

Thank you!!

Comment: [Reveal.js has several themes](https://revealjs.com/themes/). Which are you using?

Comment: The simple theme!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step would be to go to the `<head></head>` section. At the bottom make a new `<style></style>` tag for your custom CSS styling.

### To align a piece of text on a slide in reveal.js

Create a new class called left.

`.left {  }`
Inside your class, put `text-align: left;`. Your code should look like this:

```
<style>
  .left {
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>
```

In your HTML, add the `left` class to any of your elements. Eg.

```
<section class="left">Slide 1</section>
```

Or:

```
<section>
  I'm just normal text.
  <p class="left">But I'm not!</p>
</section>
```

### Change the font size of an element in reveal.js

The first thing to do is create a new class as we did for aligning text.

```
<head>
  <!-- Custom Styles For Our Presentation -->
  <style>
    .left {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .size {
      
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Then add the following:
`font-size: /*custom font size*/;`
You can change the size there. CSS also has some built-in styles for this such as `large`, `medium` and `small`.
After that, just add the class to your chosen elements. You can also add to classes to one element like this: `<section class="left size">Slide 1</section>`.
Your finishing code could be something like this:

```
<head>
  <!-- Custom Styles For Our Presentation -->
  <style>
    .left {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .size {
      font-size: 80px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">
      <section class="left size">Slide 1</section>
      <section>Slide 2 <p class="left">Text aligned left</p></section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```